# asp.net core PascalCase for JsonResult for just one method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller

Using MVC Core.  Json results are being sent to client modifying the properties!  It is converting everything to camelCase.  I would like to change just one method to return the data without being modified. (Since I have no control over the entire project in visual studio I cannot change the global mvc settings)  Currently this is messing up my method and converting everything to camelCase:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CustomerSearch(string search)
{
...
// This is changing the json to camelCase
return Json(lstCustomers);
}
```

I am trying to leave it as default by using this return:

```cs
var pascalCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
pascalCaseFormatter.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
return Json(lstCustomers, pascalCaseFormatter);
```

However this returns an error 500 from server.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind telling us which error it returns?

Comment: It returns an error 500 from server.

Comment: Yeah -- we see that from your question, but *what* is the error. There is usually a text payload/body that gives the error some context or describes it in some way.

Comment: And I don't know if it's a typo in your question, but you create a `camelCaseFormatter`, but then set a property in some `pascalCaseFormatter`... but then you use `camelCaseFormatter` in your return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not change casing (Pascal-casing when using normal c# naming conventions)

```cs
return Json(lstCustomers, new JsonSerializerOptions());
```

And this will return camel-casing

```cs
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};
return Json(lstCustomers, serializeOptions);
```

Finally, what OP is trying will throw an exception:

```cs
return Json(lstCustomers, new JsonSerializerSettings());

System.InvalidOperationException: Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions'.
```

Tested using an asp.net Core 5 app.

Comment: Roar, it worked perfect!  Thank you very much.